# how to disable additional cuda information when importing tensorflow

Tags: nvidia, cuda

when I typed python commands relative to cuda in my tensorflow environment I got a few information about cuda, how can I disable/enable them?

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
```

Comment: You could try to set the environment variable `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` to 1-3..